# Is it possible to stream an audio playlist to peers using webRTC?

Tags: webrtc, icecast

In essence, I'd like to create an online radio where users can upload music to be played at specific times. Is webRTC capable of this or would I be better served going with something like Icecast?

Comment: WebRTC is primarily for direct browser to browser communication. If you are going to upload music to a server you might as well stream it to the client browsers using standard HTTP.

Comment: Note, for Icecast you'll need a source client. In your case one with a backend that can handle all the uploading and scheduling. Might look at liquidsoap and airtime.

Comment: Why would you want to mess with WebRTC for this?  Icecast and similar are far more compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC is about peer2peer communications.

If users would upload their media on to your server, then you would need to use some WebRTC-compatible media streaming software (such as Wowza, for example) for serving the media via WebRTC; in other words, the server would have to act as a WebRTC peer.

For the described task WebRTC is not the case, on my opinion. Icecast & Co would be better suitable for the task. Basically, I believe that it can be built using just HTML5 (and JavaScript, probably).

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick with Icecast and Liquidsoap for now.